# Checking if a JSON property exists

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, yahoo-finance, urlfetch

I am importing stock JSON data from Yahoo Finance to import into Google Sheets for a personal stock tracker using a custom function:

```
function _yahoofinance(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker)
            + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
            + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
            + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
  ;

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    const price       = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].price.regularMarketPrice)     ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].price.regularMarketPrice.fmt; 
    const divYield    = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield)  ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.raw * 100;
    const payoutRatio = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio)    ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio.raw * 100;
    const marketCap   = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.marketCap)      ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.marketCap.fmt;
    const fwdPE       = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.forwardPE)      ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.forwardPE.fmt;
    const revenue     = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.totalRevenue)   ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.totalRevenue.fmt;
    const revGrowth   = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.revenueGrowth)  ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.revenueGrowth.raw * 100;
    const earnGrowth  = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.earningsGrowth) ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.earningsGrowth.raw * 100;
    const freeCash    = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.freeCashflow)   ? '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.freeCashflow.fmt;


      return [[divYield, payoutRatio, marketCap, fwdPE, revenue, revGrowth, earnGrowth, freeCash]];
  }
}

function _isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === undefined;
}
```

Please see an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VGwVWw2ZFW0qYQjxN6jomZLyxssKp48ykE5jGWIqMFA/edit?usp=sharing) (tab `JSON`).

The problem is: not every ticker will have every property that I'm requesting from Yahoo. I have tried in many different ways to deal with this:

```
const payoutRatio = _isEmpty(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio)

function _isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === undefined;
}
```

But none of this works. In the example sheet I am trying to pull data on ticker `0P0001703K.SW`, which is an ETF, so it will not have all the properties that stocks have. Google Sheets returns an error:

```
#Error! TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalRevenue' of undefined (line 19).
```

It is driving me half insane :D I have been trying to catch such errors in so many ways. My question is: what is the proper way to check if a property exists, and if not, just return `-` and move on to the next property? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT] Solution:

```
function _yahoofinance(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker)
            + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
            + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
            + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
  ;

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    const price       = quote.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.regularMarketPrice?.fmt     || '-'; 
    const divYield    = quote.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.dividendYield?.raw  ?  '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.raw * 100;
    const payoutRatio = quote.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.payoutRatio?.raw    ?  '-' : quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio.raw * 100;
    const revenue     = quote.quoteSummary.result[0]?.financialData?.totalRevenue?.fmt   || '-';

    return [[price, divYield, payoutRatio, revenue]];
  }
}
```

Comment: I would look at [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: You can try `your_json[property_name] === undefined` to check if this property exists

Comment: I believe this is what I'm doing with `_isEmpty()` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead of your `_isEmpty()` function because you check if `quote.quoteSummary.result[0].financialData.totalRevenue` is empty but error says *'totalRevenue' of undefined*. That means that `financialData` is undefined and it throws error even before it goes to your isEmpty function.

In your example it would be something like:

```js
const quote = {
  quoteSummary: {
    result: [{}]
  }
}
const revenue = quote.quoteSummary.result?.[0]?.financialData?.totalRevenue?.fmt || '-';
console.log(revenue);
```

Comment: I tried this too --- it did not work :( Same result.

Comment: It can't give the same error (_totalRevenue of undefined_) because this code checks if it is undefined. Are you sure you are looking at the right place / implemented it right way?

Comment: GoogleScripts may not support the newer features of the language

Comment: You are correct; I don't know what I did wrong the first time (weeks ago) but then it didn't work. I could have saved myself a lot of frustration! One question though: the "raw" values I sometimes want to multiply by 100 (if the value exists; see code in opening post), for instance `const divYield = quote.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.dividendYield?.raw  || '-';` Right now, with your solution, it returns the raw value. How can I, if the propery exists, return the raw value x 100?

Comment: @Pr0no You can use ternary operation like you did in your solution ('?:') instead of OR (`||`) but I'd do it simply on a new line to keep it easy to read.

Comment: @catgirlkelly Google AppScripts [uses V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) and [V8 supports optional chaining](https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining) but nice catch.